# Redirect sys.stdin and sys.stdout

Tags: python, stdout, stdin

I'm trying to redirect stdin and stdout. My first attempt I tried this code:

```
from sys import stdin, stdout

stdin = open('in.txt','r')
stdout = open('out.txt','w')

for line in stdin:
    print(line)
```

It reads from `in.txt`, but print still writes to the terminal.

A second version does write output to `out.txt`:

```
import sys

sys.stdin = open('in.txt','r')
sys.stdout = open('out.txt','w')

for line in sys.stdin:
    print(line)
```

So what's the difference between these two programs? Why doesn't the first one work?

Finally, I tried this version, which also works:

```
from sys import stdin, stdout

stdin = open('in.txt', 'r')
stdout = open('out.txt', 'w')

for line in stdin:
    print(line, file=stdout)
```

Comment: Related: [Redirect stdout to a file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675728/redirect-stdout-to-a-file-in-python)

Comment: "What's the difference?" -- one creates a new local-to-your-current-module variable, _overriding_ what you created with the `import` without changing the other module at all; the other one reaches into the `sys` module and changes its contents. "Explicit is better than implicit", to quote the Zen of Python; if you want to override another module's contents, you need to do it explicitly.